# How to unlock android phone through code remotely

Tags: android

I have written an application that locks android phone remotely. That is when a special code is sent from server then application locks the phone based on the special code. This is the code I am using.

```
if (!mDPM.isAdminActive(mDeviceAdminSample)) {
        // try to become active – must happen here in this activity, to get result
        Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,mDeviceAdminSample);
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,"Admin is added to do security operation.");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        } else {
        // Already is a device administrator, can do security operations now.
        mDPM.lockNow();
        }
```

The above code is working and it's locking the phone.

I am able to unlock the phone by entering password from soft keypad. Is there any way to unlock it through code?

My question is how to unlock the phone through code.(This unlocking should be done remotely in the manner I explained for locking)

Comment: What is min API and have you added uses-permission in your mainManifest?

Answer (score 6):

I believe you cannot override the built-in screen-lock unless you make your own device like Samsung and HTC do. However, by having your customers use your own screen-lock-like app you probably can achieve what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

I do not think your remote unlock goal is achievable.

The way Android is set up, is that many apps may have Device Administrator privilege, and any Device Administrator can issue a lock command, but the unlock has to come from the user.

I can suggest one thing you to simplify this: Your app could try to remove the key lock password, and then the user can use the device without a code simply by sliding a finger on the screen.

Now there is a snag in what I suggested, if your app is not the only device administrator.  In that case, some other administrator app could set a minimum password length (or some other password restriction) which would prevent your app from clearing the screen lock password.

If your goal is to help a user that forgot his/her screen lock password, then your server could invent a new password, inform the user what the new password is, and also send the new password to your app and your app could apply the password.  The user can then unlock the phone.  Do not worry, it is not as complicated as it sounds.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to write that - There is no way to unlock phone from code. If you find any way to do that - no warranty to work. So there is no way to remote unlock, writing custom lock screens, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use mDPM.resetPassword("", 0)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#resetPassword(java.lang.String, int)

When set password string as "", current password is replaced with empty values & screen lock disappears.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
KeyguardManager manager = (KeyguardManager)context.getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
kl = manager.newKeyguardLock("my-remote-app");
kl.disableKeyguard();
```

//for reenabling keyguard on exit (if you need)

```
onDestroy() {
kl.reenableKeyguard();
}
```

this works <=ICS.
This is a deprecated api, they suggested you to use the flags from WindowManager for similar effect. Although I failed to generate the similar effect using the WindowManger.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I have used it in GNote N7000 with ICS and it works. Did you put the extra permission to use the KeyguardManager? Otherwise your intent may get killed due to SecurityException.

Comment: Also you can add the NEW_TASK flag, when spawning the unlock intent.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that I'm not an Android developer, but:

If you look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html), it looks like you can ask the WindowManager to dismiss the key guard if you have the right permission, even if you're in "secure lock" mode.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, we cant unlock password protected phone programatically.

Comment: You don't even have a name.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to write a "custom lockscreen".
Sure, it's not the easiest way, but it would work as you can do everything you want with your own lockscreen.
If you are considering that solution, feel free to contact me, I'll give you some useful links.
Cheers!

Comment: Android does not support costume lock screens

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman It almost does support it, but not with an official API. In order to have a custom lock screen, your app will need to be the default launcher. Here are some example apps: http://www.androidauthority.com/best-music-player-apps-for-android-208990/ https://www.androidpit.com/best-android-lock-screen-apps

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman It worked back then too. Just different apps, like WidgetLocker, for example.